# Create React app yarn 3.6.4 stabile version

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg-v3, yarn-v3, corepack

I am creating a new React application using yarn 3.6.4. The following commands: corepack enable, yarn init -2 set the packages.json and yarn.lock. with yarn add typeacript, eslint, prettier I defined the dependencies. Now I would like to do : yarn start to start the app running in port, but error occurs. What am.I.misaing? Îs yarn init -2 replaces yarn create reat-app ?

I need to have a skeleton of a React app with yarn 3.6.4 . I am also confused about non rezo installs, zero nstalls....node-modules If they should be or not